# Show Loading Widget When Button is Clicked

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, button

I have a "Loading..." element as a div right now. Right now, it runs whenever I come to the page it is on, but I'd like for it to only come up when I click on a button and go away when that function is done loading.

The "Loading..." div code:

```
<div id="MSG" class="ui-widget-overlay ui-front" title="">
                <div class="center spinner-preview" id="spinner-preview">Loading....</div>
         </div>
```

And I'd like for it to only activate when the following button is clicked and that is currently loading.

```
 <div id="Verify"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Verify Login & Save" /></div>
```

I can't seem to get it to work though. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "when that function is done loading" - where is that function? Show it plz.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your loading div display hidden.
2. on click of you button show your div and then perform your task.
3. hide div again.